# re-writing the same data during insertion in dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, insert

this is my method in DynamoDb manager class which does a simple job of uploading the values in DynamoDB table. This method is working fine, that is it is inserting data into table, but the problem is that everytime it is getting called by some button activity, it is re-writing the previously inserted values and not inserting new values.
If some can help me then it would be great!

```
public static ArrayList<UserUpdBuks> uploadNewBooks(){
    AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = NavigationDrawerActivity.clientManager
            .ddb();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddb);

    try{
            for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
                UserUpdBuks up = new UserUpdBuks();
                up.setAuthor(Upload_BookDetailsPage.uBookAuthor);
                up.setBook_Name(Upload_BookDetailsPage.uBookName);
                Log.d(TAG, "Uploading New Book");
                mapper.save(up);
                Log.d(TAG, "Book Uploaded !");

            }
    }catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error inserting users");
        NavigationDrawerActivity.clientManager
                .wipeCredentialsOnAuthError(ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is the part of other class where my above method is being called:

```
this.textViewBookName= (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.valueUploadBookName);
this.textViewBookName.setText(product.getName());

this.textViewBookAuthor= (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.valueUploadBookAuthor);
this.textViewBookAuthor.setText(product.getAuthor());

uBookName = product.getName();
uBookAuthor = product.getAuthor();

clientManager = new AmazonClientManager(this);

final Button uploadNewBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
uploadNewBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Upload_BookDetailsPage", "Submit button clicked.");

            new GetBookListTask().execute();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope `Upload_BookDetailsPage.uBookAuthor` and `Upload_BookDetailsPage.uBookName` are **static** values which are never getting changed in the code or in the for loop.

```
up.setAuthor(Upload_BookDetailsPage.uBookAuthor);
up.setBook_Name(Upload_BookDetailsPage.uBookName);
```

Comment: Yup they are static values

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, basically it was missing the primary key insertion value, hence it was re-writing the same value.